Not able to install stable diffusion , getting this error
venv "C:\sd\stable-diffusion-webui\venv\Scripts\Python.exe"
Python 3.10.6 (tags/v3.10.6:9c7b4bd, Aug  1 2022, 21:53:49) [MSC v.1932 64 bit (AMD64)]
Version: v1.9.3
Commit hash: <hash>
Installing torch and torchvision
C:\sd\stable-diffusion-webui\venv\Scripts\python.exe: No module named pip
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\sd\stable-diffusion-webui\launch.py", line 48, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\sd\stable-diffusion-webui\launch.py", line 39, in main
    prepare_environment()
  File "C:\sd\stable-diffusion-webui\modules\launch_utils.py", line 380, in prepare_environment
    run(f'"{python}" -m {torch_command}', "Installing torch and torchvision", "Couldn't install torch", live=True)
  File "C:\sd\stable-diffusion-webui\modules\launch_utils.py", line 115, in run
    raise RuntimeError("\n".join(error_bits))
RuntimeError: Couldn't install torch.
Command: "C:\sd\stable-diffusion-webui\venv\Scripts\python.exe" -m pip install torch==2.1.2 torchvision==0.16.2 --extra-index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu121
Error code: 1
Press any key to continue . . .

I have tried installing and adding every required thing to the environement variables, still not getting the solution.

Does this answer your question? Stable Diffusion (Couldn't Install Torch & Pip Version)

"No module named pip" means your virtualenv is broken. Delete the venv and try again.

Seems to be a problem with installing torch, not Python itself. See Installing torch and torchvision and RuntimeError: Couldn't install torch.  Torch is called PyTorch and is one of the many packages that can be loaded into Python. There are Python version that come without PyTorch. Check Anaconda.

Question doesn't identify the problem correctly

Thanks everyone for your answers
well , my problem is solved where I just have to delete and reinstall the venv folder i.e; virtual environment folder with the activation script.
please go through the below process in case you are encountering the same problem

rmdir /s <venv_directory>
python -m venv <venv_directory>
<venv_directory>\Scripts\activate

Clear explanation - Open the cmd and navigate to the script folder
Delete and reinstall it and run the activate command.

Glad I could help via my comment. ;-)




I am not sure about it exactly but it may help,
do try to change the version of pytorch and torchvision from 2.1.2 to 2.2.1 and 0.16.2 to 0.17.0 in requirements.txt and try again,
2)
try to clone it in other directory than C/, it will work as expected, i just tried, somehow it is having some issues in C due to some conflict with global environment or what, good luck
